# Magento 1.9 - problem with librabries conflict - nouislider.js and prototype.js

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, 3rd-party-library

I have in code following libraries:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/lib/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/lib/jquery/noconflict.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/mage/cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/mage/translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/lib/lodash/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/lib/momentjs/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/lib/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/lib/noUislider/nouislider.js"></script>
```

And I have a problem with a slider on mobiles. On PC's it works well but on mobiles, touching doesn't work (on the phone and on PC dev tools also). When I touch some point on slider button moves to this position but I get the error message (one time) in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.each is not a function
>       at TouchList.findAll (prototype.js:883)
>       at fixEvent (nouislider.js:1473)
>       at HTMLDivElement.method (nouislider.js:1387)

When I try to drag button and slide it to side, button doesn't move but in consolthe e I get error above but two times (same error).

It looks like the problem is somewhere libraries nouislider.js and prototype.js. If I disable prototype.js for moment, slider working fine. Because prototype.js is necessary in project to other feature I need to solve this problem. Any idea how to do it?

I am not best in JS but job must be done so I really need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would be interested to know whether an updated prototype library may fix this conflict. Try https://github.com/leytech/Leytech_PrototypeUpdate for a clean way to update prototype.js

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I removed prototype.js from templates where the conflict appears by

jspath_to_library/prototype.js

in xml file. It was enough this time.

Answer (score 0):

I simply added:

TouchList.prototype.each = Array.prototype.each;
TouchList.prototype._each = Array.prototype._each;

to noUislider.min.js at beginning and seems to have fixed my issue(s).

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this issue by upgrading prototype.js to its latest version.

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3.0/prototype.js